# Only display parent node if no child node exists XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to have the table display ONLY parent nodes that do not have child nodes? I only want items AT-2 and AT-3 to display in the table...

XML:

```
<root>
   <Item type="Acceptance Test">
      <jav_acc_id>AT-1</jav_acc_id>
      <Relationships>
         <Item type="Acceptance Test Requirements">
            <related_id>
               <Item type="Requirement">
                  <item_number>REQ-1</item_number>
               </Item>
            </related_id>
         </Item>
      </Relationships>
   </Item>
   <Item type="Acceptance Test">
      <jav_acc_id>AT-2</jav_acc_id>
   </Item>
   <Item type="Acceptance Test">
      <jav_acc_id>AT-3</jav_acc_id>
   </Item>
</root>
```

This is what I have so far that displays it all
XSLT1.0:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <html>
        <body>
        <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Acceptance Test</th>
            <th>Requirement</th>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="Item">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="jav_acc_id"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select=".//item_number"/>
                        <xsl:if test=".//item_number='' or not(.//item_number)">
                        <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </td>
                </tr>   
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for the absence of `<Relationships>` with `<xsl:if>` like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Item">
  <tr>

    <xsl:if test="not(Relationships)">
      ...
    </xsl:if>

  </tr>   
</xsl:for-each>
```